# question about templates

Tags: c++

i have following  code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
namespace rel_ops{
    template<class t>bool operator!=(const t& x, const t& y){ return !(x==y);}
    template <class t>bool operator>(const t& x,const t& y){ return y<x;}
    template <class t>bool operator <=(const t& x,const t& y){ return !(y<x);}
    template  <class t> bool operator>=(const t& x,t& y) { return ! (x<y);}
    }
int main(){
    int x,y;

    cin>>x>>y;


     return 0;
}
```

i have question 
how implement it in main function? how implements its operators in main function

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: use this operators   using this templates with x and y

Comment: You're misunderstanding their purpose. They are there to help classes define all the comparison operators. Once they're defined, you just use them like `x < y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
using namespace rel_ops;
```

Note that rel_ops is already defined in std. You do not need to redefine this namespace and its contents in your code. To use the definition already present in std, you use just:

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std::rel_ops;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation and a nice example:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/rel_ops/